# Installing Logstash on Kubernetes and Sending logs to AWS ElasticSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kubernetes, logstash

I am trying to set up a monitoring solution for apps running on Kubernetes via AWS elasticsearch.

To ship logs I am using filebeat --> Logstash --> AWS ElasticSearch and it's proving to be a nightmare so far :(

To ship logs from logstash, I need to use amazon_es output plugin but I am getting different errors

Below is the manifest file for logstash that I am using

```
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: logstash-configmap
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  logstash.yml: |
    http.host: "0.0.0.0"
    path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
  logstash.conf: |
    # all input will come from filebeat, no local logs
    input {
      beats {
        port => 5044
      }
    }
    filter {
      if [message] =~ /^\{.*\}$/ {
        json {
          source => "message"
        }
      }
      if [ClientHost] {
        geoip {
          source => "ClientHost"
        }
      }
    }
    output {
        amazon_es {
            hosts => [ "https://vpc-eks***********.es.amazonaws.com:443" ]
            region => "eu-west-1"
            index => "devtest-logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"            
        }
    }
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: logstash-deployment
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: logstash
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: logstash
        image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5044
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/config
          - name: logstash-pipeline-volume
            mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: logstash-configmap
          items:
            - key: logstash.yml
              path: logstash.yml
      - name: logstash-pipeline-volume
        configMap:
          name: logstash-configmap
          items:
            - key: logstash.conf
              path: logstash.conf
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: logstash-service
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    app: logstash
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5044
    targetPort: 5044
  type: ClusterIP
```

```
│ [INFO ] 2019-08-27 13:20:50.114 [LogStash::Runner] agent - No persistent UUID file found. Generating new UUID {:uuid=>"fb22e6cb-d7bb-4735-a05a-da4a2e4dabde", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/uuid"}                              │
│ [ERROR] 2019-08-27 13:20:55.290 [Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>] registry - Tried to load a plugin's code, but failed. {:exception=>#<LoadError: no such file to load -- logstash/outputs/amazon_es>, :path=>"logstash/outp │
│ uts/amazon_es", :type=>"output", :name=>"amazon_es"}                                                                                                                                                                               │
│ [ERROR] 2019-08-27 13:20:55.295 [Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>] agent - Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::PluginLoadingError", :message=>"Could │
│ n't find any output plugin named 'amazon_es'. Are you sure this is correct? Trying to load the amazon_es output plugin resulted in this error: no such file to load -- logstash/outputs/amazon_es", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logst │
│ ash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugins/registry.rb:211:in `lookup_pipeline_plugin'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugin.rb:137:in `lookup'", "org/logstash/plugins/PluginFactoryExt.java:200:in `plugin'", "or │
│ g/logstash/plugins/PluginFactoryExt.java:137:in `buildOutput'", "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:50:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:23:in `initialize'", "/usr/ │
│ share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:36:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:325:in `block in converge_state'"]}
```

so far i haven't been able to find anything as the container goes into crash loop. Any help would be great

Comment: Please post the manifest for your workload. More people might be able to help you if you do that.

Comment: Tried to connect filebeat directly to AWS ES but that also failed `│ 2019-08-27T13:49:25.454Z    ERROR    pipeline/output.go:100    Failed to connect to backoff(elasticsearch(https://vpc-eks-devtest-oqr3xrffk2kw7rlxpxmw4c2vme.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com:443)): Connection marked as failed because │
│  the onConnect callback failed: cannot retrieve the elasticsearch license: unauthorized access, could not connect to the xpack endpoint, verify your credentials   `

Answer (score 0):

you need to install amazon_es plugin to fix this issue.

Include this in your dockerfile.

`RUN logstash-plugin install  logstash-output-amazon_es`